# Swipe anywhere in UITableViewCell to delete

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, swipe

I'm sure this question must have been asked before but various Google searches are coming up short:

In my Objective-C application I have a UITable whose rows implement swipe-to-delete.  This works well but only when the user swipes on the background to the cell.  Unfortunately, most of the area of the cell is taken up with either a UITextField or several UIButtons.

How can make swipe-to-delete active on these other components contained in the UITableViewCell?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26251559/903544

Comment: Thanks René.  That answer worked.  Unfortunately, I can't mark this as the correct answer because it's only a comment.

Comment: Check this answer to a similar question: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/26251559/903544](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26251559/903544)

Comment: Changed it to an answer :)